# How to get SalesQuoteId in BusinessCentral API?

Tags: api, dynamics-nav, dynamics-business-central

Im trying to extract all data from Business Central to DB using API. I can extract most of the entities but for extracting Sales Quotes it is looking for a `salesQuotes({id})`

```
GET businesscentralPrefix/companies({id})/salesQuotes({id})
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/api-reference/v2.0/api/dynamics_salesquote_get

i do not know where to get the `salesQuotes({id})` from.

Comment: You should get ID from quote list

Comment: There is no endpoint for Quote list

Answer (score 2):

You can call the API without the ID to get the full list of Sales Quotes:

```
GET businesscentralPrefix/companies({id})/salesQuotes
```

Comment: without ID it fails-

{
    "error": {
        "code": "Application_DialogException",
        "message": "The maximum Invoice Discount Amount that you can apply is 24.24.  CorrelationId:  d1cb3caf-66ca-4fa5-8546-b1192270ccff."
    }
}

Comment: That is an internal error in Business Central - not an issue with the API.
The API works as expected.
You would have to investigate the data on the Sales Quotes to figure out which one is causing the problems.